# Jquery validate not working inside nested div

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My problem is that jquery validate is not working.The firebug also doesn't show any kind of error.Below is the jquery:

```
$("#AlertForm").validate({  
    rules: {
        alertcategory: "required",
        alertsubcategory: "required",
        alertcity: "required",
        alertemail: { required: true, email: true },
        alertphone: { required: true, number: true, maxlength: 10 }         
    },
    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        alertcategory: "Please Select one category from dropdown",
        alertsubcategory: "Please select subcategory based on category above.",
        alertcity: "Please select one city from dropdown",
        alertcity: "Please enter your email id",
        alertphone: "Please enter your phone number"
    },
});
```

I have put this code in document ready function.I have also provided name,class,id to each elements of form,still didn't got success.Also,my form consists of various div tags inside it.Please help.

My form code:

```
<div class="content_part_two">
         <form method = "post" class ="AlertForm" id="AlertForm" name="AlertForm" action="#">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 content_part ">
                    <img src="<?php echo URL;?>img/alert.png"  />
                    <h3>Create Free Alert</h3>
                    <div class="full_part sell_part">
                         <div class="half_part">

                            <select name="FreeAlertSelect"   class="selectpiker" id ="FreeAlertSelect" >
                                    <option selected="selected">I Want to Sell-Remind Me</option>

                             </select>
                         </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="full_part">
                         <div class="half_part pull-left">
                            <select name="AlertSelectCategory"  class="selectpiker" id = "AlertSelectCategory" >
                                    <option value="null">Category</option>
                                    <option>Slow</option>
                                    <option >Medium</option>
                                    <option>Fast</option>
                                    <option>Faster</option>
                             </select>
                         </div>
                         <div class="half_part pull-right">
                            <select name="AlertSelectSubcategory"   class="selectpiker" id = "AlertSelectSubcategory" >
                                    <option value="null">Sub Category</option>
                                    <option>Slow</option>
                                    <option>Medium</option>
                                    <option>Fast</option>
                                    <option>Faster</option>
                             </select>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="full_part">
                         <div class="half_part pull-left  col-md-offset-3">
                            <select name="AlertCity"   class="selectpiker" id="AlertCity" >
                                    <option value="null">City</option>
                                    <option>Slow</option>
                                    <option>Medium</option>
                                    <option>Fast</option>
                                    <option>Faster</option>
                             </select>
                         </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="full_part">
                         <div class="half_part pull-left">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="AlertEmail" name="AlertEmail"/>
                         </div>
                         <div class="half_part pull-right">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone"  id="AlertPhone" name="AlertPhone"/><span id="erralertmsg"></span>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="full_part sell_part">
                         <div class="half_part">
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name = "FreeAlertSubmit" id="FreeAlertSubmit"  />

                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add your form code.

Comment: You've got two `alertcity` keys and an extra comma at the end. I'm guessing the second should actually be `alertemail`?

Comment: I did what you mentioned.Still no errors, and validate plugin still not performing as it should..

Comment: NONE of your HTML field `name` attributes actually match any of the names you've used within the `.validate()` method. How do you expect the plugin to find the fields? Otherwise, it would be working: http://jsfiddle.net/ff7qzLu8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- JavaScript is case sensitive.  As one example, you're using `name="AlertEmail"` within the HTML markup while using `alertemail` within the `.validate()` method.  These must match exactly and yours do not.
- You're also using `alertcategory` and `alertsubcategory` but you do not have any fields that contain those names. Your actual element names are `AlertSelectCategory` and `AlertSelectSubcategory`.

The names you use within the `.validate()` method must exactly match each field's `name` in your HTML markup.  Otherwise, the plugin will not be able to find them.

```
    rules: {
        AlertSelectCategory: "required",
        AlertSelectSubcategory: "required",
        AlertCity: "required",
        AlertEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        AlertPhone: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            maxlength: 10
        }
    },
```

- And finally, you must use `value=""`, not `value="null"`, on the first `option` element if you want a `select` element to be validated as `required`.

  ```
  <select name="AlertSelectCategory">
      <option value="">Category</option>
      ....
  ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ff7qzLu8/**